# Creating a new file within a jar?

Tags: java, deployment, file-io, jar

Is it possible to create a new file within a jar while a program is running? I.e to store some user specified data. Or do the files have to be created within the OS and can't be added to the jar itself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The JVM loads the classes from a JAR file. With the default classloader it is not possible reflect the change in your jar file to the program running. The web servers uses their own  classloader to reflect the changes in the class files in runtime. You can write your own classloader, look here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Classloader
and 
http://www.javablogging.com/java-classloader-2-write-your-own-classloader/